# why cleaning text function doens't work without decoding to UTF8?

Tags: python-2.7, utf-8, text-mining, graphlab, sframe

I wrote the following function in python 2.7 to clean the text but it doesn't work without decoding the tweet variable to utf8

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
def clean_tweet(tweet):
    tweet = re.sub(u"[^\u0622-\u064A]", ' ', tweet, flags=re.U)
return tweet
if __name__ == "__main__":
      s="sadfas    سيبس sdfgsdfg/dfgdfg ffeee منت   منشس      يت??بمنشس//تبي منشكسميكمنشسكيمنك ٌاإلا رًاٌااًٌَُ"
      print "not working "+clean_tweet(s)
      print "working "+clean_tweet(s.decode("utf-8"))
```

Could any one explain why? 
Because I don't want to use the decoding as it makes the manipulation of the text in Sframe in graphlab is  too slow.

Comment: Because UTF-8 encoded text isn't text, it's bytes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, how can I solve that without decoding?

Comment: You rewrite Python so that it doesn't need the bytes to be decoded in order to treat them as text.

Comment: I tried the following code but it gave me strange charters
tweet = re.sub("[^ا-ي]", ' ', tweet, flags=re.U)

 سيبس                       � � ت   � � شس      يت  ب� � شس  تبي � � ش� س� ي� � � شس� ي� � �  � ا� � ا ر� ا� اا� � � �